# The circle always spins near the text "Available Networks" in Wi-Fi setting in Ubuntu Settings(Ubuntu 20.04.2 Desktop)

Tags: networking, gnome, network-manager

The circle always spins near the text “可用网络” in Wi-Fi setting in Ubuntu Settings. And there is no avaliable network to connecting.
I restarted NetworkManager.service, it did not work.
I edited /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf with replacing as `managed=true` and saved, it did not work either.
I used `nmcli` command, it did not work.
I rebooted Ubuntu, it did not work.
My computer: ASUS Laptop
My WLAN adapter: Qualcomm Atheros
Machine state: physical machine

Comment: You will get better help if you translate your output. In your previous question, you stated that some of your output said "Wi Fi adapter not found." If still accurate, that's important information that needs to be in your Question above.

Comment: @user535733 I never use GNOME Control Center in English. The English meaning of “可用网络” may be “available networkings”

Comment: Does it mean "looking for available network"?